# Why is scanf ignoring the last value?

Tags: c, string, parsing, csv, scanf

I'd like to read in a line of CSV from the command line. The user enters it in the form `age, HH:MM:SS, number`.

I've written the following:

```
int age;
char timestamp[8];
int number;

scanf("%d,%8[^,],%d", &age, timestamp, &number;
printf("%d, %s, %d", age, timestamp, number);
```

When I enter `23, abcd, 9` it prints `23, abcd, 9`
When I enter `23, abcdefghijklmno, 9` it prints `23, abcdefgh, 0`

How can I fix this?

Comment: you have a bucket that can hold 8 liters of water (timestamp[8]), and are pouring in 15 liters (abcdefghijklmno) of water. why are you surprised that only 8 liters fit into the bucket?

Comment: I assumed the %8 made it only read the first 8. Is there a way to make it simply stop reading after 8 and skip to the next field?

Comment: well, you told scanf to expect 8 characters, followed by a comma. but after those 8 chars are loaded, you DON'T have a comma, you have an `i`, so the rest of the scan pattern fails.

Comment: Aside: `char timestamp[8];` --> `char timestamp[9];` to allow for nul terminator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weak format used in `scanf()` and UB

`%8[^,]` (read 8 `char` that are not `','`) reads `" HH:MM:S"` into space that is too small [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706202/why-is-scanf-ignoring-the-last-value/35706894#comment59090383_35706202).  So if the undefined behavior of storing 8 `char` and a null character into `timestamp[8]` does not kill the code, attempting to read the 2nd `S` and match against a `','` will stop the scan [@Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b).  Not checking the return value, (a big no-no), further hides the fact `number` is not written.

```
char timestamp[8];
//     12345678
// age, HH:MM:SS, number
scanf("%d,%8[^,],%d", &age, timestamp, &number;`
```

Instead

```
char buf[100];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);

// 1 bigger for the null character
char timestamp[8+1];

//                  v-- add space              check result --v
if (sscanf(buf, "%d, %8[^,],%d", &age, timestamp, &number) == 3) {
  printf("%d, %s, %d", age, timestamp, number);
} else {
  puts("Input data scan failed");
}
```

---

`scanf()` is evil.  Save time, avoid headaches.  Use `fgets()`.
This ad brought to you by the "Practice Safe Input" committee.

Answer (score 1):

check it out.
Declaring a small size..
`timestamp[8]`

Rather have something like `timestamp[16]`.In this case name length can be maximum 16.

Also `%8` is consuming upto 8 characters. So that is another reason.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to increase the maximum length; I simply want it to find the next integer after reading 8 chars. Is this possibly with scanf?

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure of the length of string between the commas, you could scan the integer and comma. Use the `%n` specifier to capture the number of characters scanned. Scan up to 8 characters of the string. Then use `strpbrk` to find the next comma and scan that comma and the final integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    char *comma = NULL;
    char csv1[] = "23, abcdefghijklmnop, 9";
    char timestamp[9]= "";
    int age = 0;
    int number = 0;
    int used = 0;

    if ( ( sscanf ( csv1, "%d ,%n %8[^,]", &age, &used, timestamp)) == 2) {
        if ( ( comma = strpbrk ( csv1 + used, ","))) {
            if ( ( sscanf ( comma, ",%d", &number)) == 1) {
                printf ( "%d, %s, %d\n", age, timestamp, number);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```